# How to return the response of a express server to change the value of a html checkbox to a js file that manages the HTML?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

So Im making a log-in where, if the user and password are correct, a checkbox's value becomes true, everything is done, but I dont know how to return the value from the server using the response from express. Here is the POST methon in the server:

```
app.post('/CTRL', function (req, res) {
  var nombre = req.body.name;
  var passw = req.body.passw;

  connection.query('SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE User=?', [nombre], function (error, results, fields) {
    if (error) {
      res.send({
        "code": 400,
        "failed": "error ocurred"
      })
    } else {
      if (results.length > 0) {
        if (results[0].Password == passw) {
          console.log('Nombre: ' + nombre + ' password: ' + passw);
          console.log('inicio de sesion exitoso!')
          res.send('Nombre: ' + nombre + ' password: ' + passw);

        }
        else {
          console.log('Contrasena incorrecta')
          res.send({
            "code": 204,
            "success": "Email and password does not match"
          });
        }
      }
      else {
        console.log('Nombre invalido');
        res.send({
          "code": 204,
          "success": "nombre incorrecto"
        });
      }
    }
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can return a json object with a boolean in it, and then you can set the checkbox value to that.

```
res.end(JSON.stringify({ loggedInSuccessfully: true }));
```

Comment: how do I 'catch' it on the handler?

Comment: what's your handler? A UI? Angular/JavaScript? You would just get a json object back from that restful call and you can do response. loggedInSuccessfully

Answer (score 0):

You should use `send` method like you do it with error handling:

```
res.send({
            "code": 200,
            "success": "Login is OK",
            "auth": true
});
```

Also please see this [article](https://blog.fullstacktraining.com/res-json-vs-res-send-vs-res-end-in-express/) to learn about difference between `send/json/end`

Comment: how do I 'catch' it on the handler?

Comment: you did it already on line with code `if (results[0].Password == passw) {`,
catched the success case, isn't it?